# Web Service для Linux-сервера на C#

Tags: c#, mono, wcf, service, linux

Я занимаюсь изучением возможности написания Web Service'a для Linux-сервера при использовании C#. Для этого необходимо использовать Mono-Framework. Как я понял, WCF в Mono имплементирован лишь относительно и у меня появилось чувство, что лучше не трогать его. Вроде бы и все основные вещи должны работать, но что-то не то...

И я вот подумал, что может лучше стоило бы воспользоваться другими фрэймворками, которые адаптированны под Mono. Я нашел несколько, но наиболее интересными мне показались лишь 3:

- [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/)
- [ServiceStack](https://servicestack.net/features)
- [NServiceBus](http://nservicebus.sourceforge.net/) (не понятно, работает вообще под моно или нет, но вроде как должен.

Есть ли у кого нибудь опыт подобной разработки и что можно было бы для этого посоветовать? Поделитесь опытом.

Или лучше вообще отказаться от такого проекта? Клиент хочет, чтобы сервер работал на Linux и на Windows без установки Tomcat (поэтому ява исключается).

Comment: Тишина второй день... Ну хотя бы опытом с моно поделитесь... Лучше чем ничего...

Comment: @Sharbag, что именно (какие сервисы) Вы хотите развернуть на этом сервере?

Если Tomcat/Java исключается, то чем не устраивает, например Apache с PHP (или Python или perl или ...)?

Или эти сервисы планируется программировать именно на C#?

Comment: А зачем WCF? Чем вам ASP.NET не угодил?

Comment: @avp, Веб сервис планируется разработать на C# (http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0). На Apache или любом другом веб сервере он потом должен запускаться. 

@VladD, эм... Что значит клиенты не умеют WCF? WCF может делать SOAP и RESTfull сервисы. Фишка в том, что веб приложение уже есть. А вот его логику и базу данных хотят перенести в веб службу разработанную на C#.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, к сожалению до сих пор исчерпывающий ответ не был дан :(

Answer (score 1):

попробуй ASP .NET, там есть asmx-файлы

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/writing_a_webservice/

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MathService.MathService" %>

using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MathService
{
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/NumberService")]
    public class MathService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int AddNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int SubtractNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 - number2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересный вариант, а без Tomcat такое будет работать?